# Skips some parts of the file while reading

Tags: string, file, lua

So I'm making a simple program in lua that asks you to write a word that contains something like "ck" or "bv", obviously the words must be on dictionary so I have a fille with over 50,000 words that are on the dictionary, the thing is that when I type words that are on the file it says that I lose, I put a print(line) for debug so I can see whats happening, I noticed that it doesnt print every word

Example:

[image]

Text file

[image]

This is the code for reading the file:

```
local words_file = io.open("words.txt", "r")
local words = {}
local contains = {"br", "gg", "in", "et", "ck", "q", "it", "el", "st", "es", "be"}
local input

math.randomseed(os.time())


for line in words_file:lines() do
  words[line] = words_file:read("*l")
  print(line)
end
print("Loaded!")
```

This is the code for the game:

```
while true do
    local contain = contains[math.random(#contains)]
    print("Write a word that contains \"" .. contain .."\"")
    input = io.read()
  if not (string.find(input, contain) and words[input:lower()]) then
    print("lol u bad")
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Please prefer text presentation over images showing rendered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `words_file:read("*l")` in your loop, you are also causing the iterator to advance through the file which is causing you to skip lines.

The default behavior for [file:lines](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:lines) is to use `l` also.

> Returns an iterator function that, each time it is called, reads the file according to the given formats. When no format is given, uses "l" as a default.

You already have the value from the line in the loop variable `line`.

you just need to do

```lua
for line in words_file:lines() do
  words[line] = true
  print(line)
end
```